# Unsure of proper column type for migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Yeah, it's a stupid question.  I'm learning Rails on the fly and googling this one hasn't yielded an answer. I'm creating a model that will store, among other things, a date.  That date, however, will not be the date that the given record is entered.  So I don't want a datestamp. I just need to store a historical date.  In reading through the rails migration guide, they say that "date" stores the date portion of datetime, which is not what I want.  So when I go to generate this model, how do I define the column?  I'm reluctant to use originated:string because I want to be able evaluate and compare these records as dates. So the question is, can I use originated:date, or will that automatically store a datestamp as opposed to the date entered in the form?  Likewise, can I use originated:string, and still be able to use ruby/rails to evaluate those records as dates?

Comment: Yes, you can use originated:string then use http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html or http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html on that string to bring it back to a date object if you wish.

Comment: Why store stringified time when he can store time?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `datetime` type.

```
create_table :my_model do |f|
  t.datetime :originated
end
```

Then you can assign to this field values of `Time`

```
m = MyModel.new
m.originated = 30.days.ago # for example
m.save
```